# Approximation Theory and optimal polynomial

Tags: polynomials, approximation

I'm just trying to work into the field of approximation theory and don't understand something.
It's in the wikipedia article about approximation theory: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_theory

This paragraph:

> For example, the graphs shown to the right show the error in approximating log(x) and exp(x) for N = 4. The red curves, for the optimal polynomial, are level, that is, they oscillate between +ε  and -ε  exactly. Note that, in each case, the number of extrema is N+2, that is, 6. Two of the extrema are at the end points of the interval, at the left and right edges of the graphs.

Those graphs are:

[image]
Explanation:

> Error between optimal polynomial and log(x) (red), and Chebyshev approximation and log(x) (blue) over the interval [2, 4]. Vertical divisions are 10−5. Maximum error for the optimal polynomial is 6.07 × 10−5.

As far as I understand it, the red function is the optimal polynomial, and the blue function is an approximating function done with the chebyshev approximation. But why are they optimal? This is the error function, but how did they get to the error function? They are oscillating n+2 times in the intervall which means they are worst-case error.
This article is messing me up a little, I hope someone can help me to understand it better.

Comment: To approximate a function: `f` over an interval : `int` by a function: `p`, you need an error criterion.  For MinMax approximations the max. abs. value of  the difference  `f-p` in `int` is chosen. You can proof (see the article you cited) that if `p` is a polynomial of degree n, the best approx. is reached, if the error attains its max. at least n+2 times in `int`. Now if you expand `f` into a series of Chebyshev polynomials and truncate after the term of degree n, you do not get the best possible poly of degree n, but a poly that is close.

Comment: Have you seen the [Chebyshev equioscillation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equioscillation_theorem)? It characterizes the optimal (a.k.a. “minimax”) approximation. (The “error function” is just the difference between the polynomial and $\log x$.)